# Scrapy: Creating Multiple Items for option selections in scraped page

Tags: python, scrapy

So, I have a spider that crawls pages, harvesting data for each item it encounters.  If the item has no options, it simply sends the item down the pipeline.  If there are options, it assembles a list of option lists, and sends a request for each unique combination of options (returns as HTML snippet, so I treat it like XML).  For each option combo, it extracts the price for the item and sends that down the pipe.  Only, it doesn't.

Here's some code:

```py
#spider code above here that does all the normal stuff, 
#plus gets and organize all options.  Then this:

for optLists in uberList:
  queryString = '?func=Options&currentOption=1&Modal=False&AddUniqueID=False&sku=' + sku + '&option1=' + optLists[0] + '&option2=' + optLists[1] + '&option3=' + optLists[2]
  reqURL = urljoin(baseAjaxURL, queryString)
  req = Request(url=reqURL,
                callback=self.parse_ajax,
                meta = {'item' : item},
               )
  self.log('simplified item: ' + reqURL, level=log.DEBUG)
  yield req
```

And the callback function:

```py
def parse_ajax(self, response):
  print 'parsing ajax'
  xxs = XmlXPathSelector(response)
  item = response.meta['item']
  item['price'] = xxs.select("normalize-space(substring-before(substring-after(.//skuMainPrice/text(), 'ppPrice:'),'/span'))").extract()[0]
  print 'parse_ajax price: ', item['price']
  return item
```

The for loop in the first method fires correctly, once for each set of options.  The Request throws an error if the callback is to a nonexistent method (which is good), but the print statements in the callback method never fire, nor is the item propagated down the pipeline.

Any advice on what I'm doing wrong or how to do it right would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Usually this behavior occurs when the Request failed, thus not calling the callback function. Can you verify the Request for the AJAX URL is correct?

Comment: I have printed out reqURL and followed the link in Firefox.  That gives me the expected HTML snippet.

Comment: Can you also verify Scrapy processes the Request with a 200 OK?

Comment: Not sure how I would do that outside the callback method.

Comment: It will show something like: `2012-10-31 16:17:16+0100 [your_spider] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.my_website>` in the stdout log.

Comment: Part of the problem seems to be in the querystring builder, the optList[0] is an int, and that was stopping the urljoin..  so it was printing just fine (for some reason), but not submitting the options to the request (the querystring was truncated after the sku).  

I changed to this:  str(optList[0]) and the output is listing the entire string now, but still not printing from within the callback method.

Comment: For whatever reason, it looks like it's not even making the request.  There's no response or 'crawled' message at all  (it seems).

Answer (score 0):

It took some time and a little desperation, but I figured this one out.  I'm using CrawlSpider for this spider, and I had to add the ajax URL to the 'allow' rule.  Without it, the url qualified for neither following nor parsing.